# Is jigaboo a bad word?

Tags: meaning

Is the word `Jigaboo` as bad as the N word or is it just like Afro-American?I found that word in google but have never seen somebody use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, it is a derogatory racial slur, for sure.

Not as "bad" as the N-word, per se—but certainly right up there in terms of vulgarity, insensitivity and offensiveness.

---

[*American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language:*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=jigaboo)

- *Offensive; Slang*—**A disparaging term for a Black person**

[*WordNet 3.0, Princeton University:*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn3.0?s=jigaboo&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0000)

- *Ethnic slur*—**Extremely offensive name for a Black person**

Comment: To quote @Sven Yargs: Your answer seems to be heavily weighted toward personal opinion as opposed to objective analysis – but this site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just opinion. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do with regard to usage of [this word]. Thanks! –  (However, the correct procedure here is to close-vote because OP has given no evidence of research, which would be quite easy in this case.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, Edwin. My crack research team's painstaking efforts did manage to locate some independent authorities who echo my opinion. Answer has been edited to reflect same. :)

Comment: Much better (though OP should have supplied this).